# what is different between design view and live view?

Tags: asp.net

i developed a webpage in visual studio 2010 by c# and asp.net Langs .

when i run my page , UI is OK in browsers like Firefox and IE but when i look at aspx file in design view i see disordered in HTML tags.

i saw this cause in another projects (i have no java script in UI)
or in adobe Dreamweaver in design view UI elements are
disordered but in live view is OK or in browsers are OK why?

my question is must we fix UI disordered or fix problems at first in design view after in live view to have not any bugs after published it in any browsers or not?or this is not important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation on Design View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4c64s41%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explicitly says that it is a *near* - WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) editor.  There are limitations to the design view listed extensively on that page.  Some of the main ones I run into are:

- "*Some character and paragraph formatting might appear differently than in a specific browser*" - The way Design View renders certain elements could easily differ from the way specific browsers render those elements.  And,
- Non-visible elements (hidden fields) and non-visible borders / outlines are shown in design view.  This pushes the rendering around a little, compared to what you'll see in a browser.
- Anything that is dynamically loaded (by server-side code or JavaScript) is not going to be reflected in Design View.

Notice especially that the linked page makes this statement:

> However, Design view is not an exact match for how the page will be
>   rendered, and you should always test the page in a browser (or in
>   multiple browsers) to be sure the page will appear as you have
>   designed it.

So don't be overly concerned about things looking funny in Design View.  Design View is usable, but it's pretty far from reality a lot of times as far as how your page will be displayed on the web.  You can use it in your early stage designs, but always use browsers for any significant testing of your layout / UI.